# run the first line as command in the console that you read from the text file

Tags: r, console, readline

I want to read the first line from the text file and then I want to run it as command in the console. This is the project in R programming. As there are many `search_tweets` queries so, I wanted them to loop as I don't want to have a large 'R script' file or not to have many files. As I am collecting data on politicians. There are many members of each political party. I want to collect members' tweets of each party and after that append them to one file of each party. On trying this strategy I have started with just two members of same party. There are two lines in the text file. These are:

1. `tweets <- search_tweets("@MaryamNSharif #PMLN", include_rts = FALSE, n = 100, since = '2018-05-13', until = '2018-05-14', retryonratelimit = TRUE)`
2. `tweets<-search_tweets("@CMShehbaz #PMLN", include_rts = FALSE, n = 100, since = '2018-05-13', until = '2018-05-14', retryonratelimit = TRUE)`

   I tried to read the lines by the code

   ```
   for(i in 1:2) {
     con <- file("extract.txt", "r")
     first_line <- readLines(con, n = 1)
     first_line
     close(con)
   }
   ```

The image is of reading the first line but it outputs as print not as a command in the console

[image: The image is of reading the first line but it outputs as print not as a command in console]
How do I remove ['1]' and extra Quotation marks from the output in console and make it a command to run directly after reading it. Please, guide me in this regard. How can I get the line by line query and run it as command without the hectic of large code and numerous number of Rscript files. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are much better ways of achieving your desired task, but for the direct question you've posed: `eval(parse(text = first_line))` will evaluate the command from a text file.

Comment: Thanks @Brian for your reply. Please guide me the other ways as I am new to R I don't know exactly. Tell me the better ways. That will be really very helpful. Thanks once again.